# passing a parameter to a function; Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want the function to return age of the employee in specified date passed to the function by parameter

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS dbo.f_Employee_Age;
GO

CREATE FUNCTION f_Employee_Age(@date DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN (SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, @date) FROM Employee)
END;
GO

SELECT dbo.f_Employee_Age('2012-12-21')
FROM Employee
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Andrew';
```

When I try to do it without the function it works perfectly fine

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, '2012-12-21')
FROM Employee
WHERE FirstName LIKE 'Andrew';
```

But if I pass the date parameter to a function I get this error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The error occurs because the select statement in your function has no WHERE clause and therefore will return a value for each row in the employee table.

Comment: FYI the difference of the years isn't someone's age; someone born 26 days ago was born last year, but it'll be some time before they are 1 year old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the function to return age of the employee in specified date passed to the function by parameter

The key here is *the* employee.  The code that works would be clearer if you wrote:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, e.BirthDate, '2012-12-21')
----------------------^ this is a value from a single row
FROM Employee e
WHERE e.FirstName LIKE 'Andrew';
```

You need to pass both values in:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_Employee_Age (
    @dob DATE,
    @date DATE
)
RETURNS INT AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(DATEDIFF(year, @dob, @date);
END;
```

Or perhaps identify the employee:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_Employee_Age (@Employee_Id @date DATE)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETURN(SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, @date)
           FROM Employee e
           WHERE e.Employee_Id = @Employee_Id
END;
```

You would call this version as:

```
dbo.f_Employee_Age(e.Employee_Id, '2012-12-21')
```

Alternatively, you could create an inline table-valued function that returns the age for *all* employees as of that date:

```
CREATE FUNCTION f_Employee_Age (
    @date DATE
)
RETURNS TABLE
    RETURN (SELECT e.*, DATEDIFF(year, e.BirthDate, @date)
            FROM employees e
           );
```

This would be called as:

```
SELECT ea.age
FROM  dbo.f_Employee_Age ea('2012-12-21') ea
WHERE ea.FirstName LIKE 'Andrew';
```

In a table-valued inline function in many ways acts like a parameterized view.

Comment: @klmtsgw You could also `APPLY` an iTVF like the first function, this has the benefit of being faster than a scalar function, while not needing to contain a reference to `employee` table